# Cannot make a static reference to the non-static method tostring() from the type Box

Tags: java

This is my Box.java

```
public class Box{ 
  private int height, width, length;

  public void setLength(int il) {
    length = il;
}
  public void setWidth(int iw) {
    width = iw;
}
  public void setHeight(int ih){
    height = ih;
}
  public int getVolume() {
    return length * width * height;
}
  public int getSurfaceArea(){
    return ((length*width)*2)+((length*height)*2)+((width*height)*2);
  }
  public String tostring(){
 return "Height is: "+"," + "Length is: "+"," + "Width is: "+"," + "Volume is: "+"," + "Surface Area is: ";
}
  public Box ( int il, int iw, int ih ) {
    length = il;
    width = iw;
    height = ih;
  }
  public Box() {}
}
```

And this is my BoxApp.java

```
public class BoxApp {
  public static void main (String[ ] args) {
    Box box1 = new Box();
    System.out.println(Box.tostring());
  }
}
```

when i run it gives me this error 
[line: 9]
Error: Cannot make a static reference to the non-static method tostring() from the type Box

Comment: You cant access instance method through class. You should use object reference (the one you just created).
Ernest showed you how.

Comment: Beside this, your implementation of `toString` makes totally no sense :/

Answer (score 2):

Should be

```
    System.out.println(box1.toString());
```

You want to call the method on the object you just created, not on the name of the class `Box`, which would be appropriate only for a `static` method, as the error message suggests.

Comment: now when i compile i get this error [line: 13]
Error: Syntax error on token "(", ; expected

Comment: Given your source above and assuming that the error is in the same file, that's two lines past the end of the file. You'd have to tell us which is line 13, and show us the code.

Comment: I sorted it out im very new at java and just following my lecture notes currently and doing exactly what they say so               public int getVolume() {
    return (length*width*height);
}                                                                   Gives me this error Error: Syntax error on token "int", @ expected

Answer (score 2):

Why you are using `BOX.toString()`? Use `box1.toString()` Or change the `toString()` method as `static` in BOX.java.

Answer (score 1):

you should call box1.tostring(), not Box.tostring()

The method isn't a static class method...

Comment: now when i compile i get this error [line: 13] Error: Syntax error on token "(", ; expected